# Next.js links refresh the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refresh, next.js

I have a Next.js blog with only 2 routes: `/` and `/posts/:slug`.

When I'm on `/posts/my-post-title`, and I click on the back link (to `/`), all is fine. The page loads fast (no refresh).

When I'm on `/`, and I click on `/posts/my-post-title`, the page refreshes and I can't figure out why. Any suggestion?

Links: [blog](https://blog.soywod.me), [sources](https://github.com/soywod/blog)

Comment: Check if you're not importing Link from material-ui instead of next/link 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found the answer...

Because I map dynamically `/posts/:slug` to `/posts?slug=:slug` [in my config](https://github.com/soywod/soywod/blob/e8270e2f9a9fd7b9eb701f37f10bfc7ffca2ec9c/scripts/routes.js#L15) (in order to reach `posts.jsx`), I need to do the same with [the Link component](https://github.com/soywod/blog/commit/f30615b5052fa3114d87f540e29f026ccc6e0814) (via the property [as](https://nextjs.org/docs#with-link)).

Comment: Heck, I was also using some dynamically created urls, and wondering why it's happening so. What a shame...

Answer (score 18):

For anyone facing the same nonsense I was: `Link` was mistakenly auto imported from `@material-ui/core`

You want:

```
import Link from 'next/link'
```

Comment: I'm sorry but that's hilarious. I had to check mine as well.

Comment: I have fallen into the same trap, goddammit

Comment: same issue here! awkward... thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I had this issue before, I thought I fixed it but again none of the above helped me solve the issue completely so I'm posting my solution.

Suppose you want to go to slot/[key] route using the link.

Then, in pages folder make a folder with name slot and inside it make a file with name [key].js, Note: Don't forget to put that [].

inside [key].js folder you can simply export the component you want to render. There are many approaches to this, let's not go into it now.

Now, while using Link use it this way,

```
                 <Link
                      href={'/slot/[key]'}
                      as = {`/slot/${your_dynamic_variable}`}
                    >
                      <a>
                        Go to the slot route
                      </a>
                    </Link>
```

Answer (score 5):

One thing to keep in mind while using Link in next.js is not to add "/" in the beginning i.e,

```
               <Link
                  href="nameoflink"
                >
                  <a>
                   Click Me
                  </a>
                </Link>
```

instead of,

```
                   <Link
                      href="/nameoflink"
                    >
                      <a>
                       Click Me
                      </a>
                    </Link>
```

If you add "/" in the beginning the page refreshes. However, you need to add "/" in the beginning if that link is in some common component accessible throughout the application like navbar, in that case, add "/" in the beginning. Give it a try if it works for you then great. I just thought I should share.

Answer (score 3):

**Use link as below: **

```
<Link href="/shop/[pid]" as={`/shop/${id}`}>
                        <a>Shop by menu</a>
                    </Link>
```

**Instead Of**

```
<Link href={`/shop/${id}`} as={`/shop/${id}`}>
                        <a>Shop by menu</a>
                    </Link>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was running into a similar issue. In my case, it was caused by having the `<a>` tag nested in another component, not as the direct child of the `Link`.

So I had:

```
<Link href='/something' passHref>
  <MyComponent />
</Link>
```

where `MyComponent` accepted `href` as a prop and looked something like:

```
<a href={ href }>
  Good things
</a>
```

This did work at first glance, as href is properly passed to the anchor tag. But it was causing a full page refresh when the link was clicked. Once I moved the `Link` and `a` tag to be in the same component as direct parent/child, it solved the issue. So now I have the standard setup all within one component:

```
<Link href='/something' passHref>
  <a>
    Good things
  </a>
</Link>
```

No more page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

simply use this :

```
 <Link href={`/blog/${encodeURIComponent(post.slug)}`}>
        <a>{post.title}</a>
 </Link>
```

reference : [If the route has dynamic segments](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-route-has-dynamic-segments)

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a problem with google chrome extensions. Try it in incognito mode, if it works the problem is in one of your browser extensions.

Answer (score -1):

if you use Head tag then this will be refresh your page

it will refresh your page because of Head tag

```
   <Head>
    <Link href="YourLink"> <Link>
     // Other codes...
    </Head>
```

remove Head tag

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

if you using next/link, you need do add passHref attribute

```
<Link href="YourLink" passHref>Name<Link>
```