# Why does my nextjs app reload the page when clicking on a next/link router Link component instead of just acting like a SPA

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I have 2 pages in my nextjs app atm, / (home) and /test

And I have 2 links on each page directing to the other, when clicking on the links I would expect the app to just re-render with the second page, but instead, the nextjs app seam to be refreshing the whole page like a regular html anchor would do.

```
// app/test/page.tsx 

import { Metadata } from "next/types";
import React from "react";
import { Layout } from "@/components/Layout/Layout"
import Link from "next/link";

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "This is a test page",
  description: "Next app description",
};

export default function Test() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>Test Page</h1>
        <Link href="/">Home Page</Link>
    </Layout>
  );
}


// app/page.tsx 

import styles from "./page.module.css";
import DemoComponent from "../components/DemoComponent/DemoComponent";
import React from "react";
import { Layout } from "@/components/Layout/Layout";
import Link from "next/link";

export const metadata = {
  title: "Home Page",
  description: "Next app description",
};

// Home stranica
export default function Home() {
  return (
      <Layout>
        <DemoComponent />
        Home Page
        <Link href="/test">Test Page</Link>
      </Layout>
  );
}
```

[image: Document request in devtools]

Q: Why is this happening, I need to be able to share state at the top level of app, and reloading will make the whole app reinitialize the top level state..?

Comment: Many answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56817613/next-js-links-refresh-the-page/71747536#71747536

Comment: For me its not anything related to wrongly importing the link from material ui, and I've tried other answers, nothing seams to work

Comment: can u provide a codepen or a caodesandbox repro sample? would be able to take a look at it better imo

Comment: I can try to spin something up in codesandbox, and I'll post a link here, as the project is in a private repo.

Comment: On that same question someone mentioned not to use a slash / - is that maybe it?

Comment: Seems you are using Next13 app Dir, do you have a layout.ts file in your app dir root ?

Comment: It was this error btw. 

"Failed to fetch RSC payload. Falling back to browser navigation"

Seams to be something related to not properly having the "use client" directive on all components / methods / files that are executed. 

I am a bit confused on how to share data / methods with the server side rendering, if I need to mark everythign with "use client"

Comment: @OdedBenDov it had nothing to do with the slash "/", you actually need the slash to indicate that you are navigating to home

Comment: OK the odd thing is that its only a problem when I switch to my company chrome profile, and on my personal chrome profile it works, must be some profile configuration in chrome thats not allowing something :/